# Restrict checkbox (one category and one subcategory at a time) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, formidable

I have a category list in my WordPress site with formidable plugin whose code is like below:

```
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_kategori_label" role="group">
    <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876986">
            <label for="field_11-97876986"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876986" value="97876986"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Prestasi</label>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876987">
                    <label for="field_11-97876987"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876987" value="97876987"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #1</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876988"><label for="field_11-97876988"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876988" value="97876988"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876989"><label for="field_11-97876989"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876989" value="97876989"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #3</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876990"><label for="field_11-97876990"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876990" value="97876990"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #4</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877081"><label for="field_11-97877081"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877081" value="97877081"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #5</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877082"><label for="field_11-97877082"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877082" value="97877082"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #6</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877083"><label for="field_11-97877083"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877083" value="97877083"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #7</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877084"><label for="field_11-97877084"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877084" value="97877084"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #8</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877085"><label for="field_11-97877085"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877085" value="97877085"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #9</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877086"><label for="field_11-97877086"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877086" value="97877086"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #10</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877087"><label for="field_11-97877087"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877087" value="97877087"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #11</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
                <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877090"><label for="field_11-97877090"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877090" value="97877090"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #12</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877047"><label for="field_11-97877047"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877047" value="97877047"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Digital</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877048"><label for="field_11-97877048"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877048" value="97877048"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Inovasi</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877052"><label for="field_11-97877052"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877052" value="97877052"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Religi</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want that user can select a main category and any one of its sub-category at a time (if sub-category exist).

What i tried so far:

```
(function($)
{
    $(':checkbox').on('click', function()
    {
        // uncheck every checkbox
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);

        // set initial variables
        var cekboks = $(this), $cariterdekat, jikapunyainduk;

        // loop
        do {
            // tick the selected cekboks
            cekboks.prop('checked', true);

            // get its closest UL
            $cariterdekat= cekboks.closest('[class^="frm_catlevel_1"]');

            // check if selected category has a parent
            jikapunyainduk = $cariterdekat.prev().is('[class^="frm_catlevel_2');

            // set the new cekboks to the one that belong to the parent
            cekboks = $('> input', $cariterdekat.prev());
        } while ( jikapunyainduk);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But it's not checked the parent category when sub-category is selected as can see at: https://bichange.wpcomstaging.com/form/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the wrapping `div` of the toggled box and check what level it sits in, and then toggle its parent if needed.

```js
(function($) {
  $(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
    // set initial variables
    var cekboks = $(this);
    let isChecked = cekboks.is(':checked');

    // uncheck every checkbox
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);

    // Find wrapping div that contains the class frm_catlevel
    $wrapper = cekboks.closest('div').parent(); // Or div[class^="frm_catlevel"]

    // Check if clicked item is 2nd level
    if ($wrapper.is('.frm_catlevel_2')) {
      $wrapper.closest('.frm_catlevel_1')
        // The first checkbox is the parent category
        .find(':checkbox').first()
        .prop('checked', true);
    }
    // If the element was already checked allow unchecking it
    if (isChecked)
      cekboks.prop('checked', true);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_kategori_label" role="group">
  <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876986">
      <label for="field_11-97876986"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876986" value="97876986"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Prestasi</label>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876987">
          <label for="field_11-97876987"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876987" value="97876987"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #1</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876988"><label for="field_11-97876988"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876988" value="97876988"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #2</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876989"><label for="field_11-97876989"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876989" value="97876989"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97876990"><label for="field_11-97876990"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97876990" value="97876990"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #4</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877081"><label for="field_11-97877081"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877081" value="97877081"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #5</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877082"><label for="field_11-97877082"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877082" value="97877082"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #6</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877083"><label for="field_11-97877083"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877083" value="97877083"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #7</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877084"><label for="field_11-97877084"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877084" value="97877084"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #8</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877085"><label for="field_11-97877085"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877085" value="97877085"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #9</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877086"><label for="field_11-97877086"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877086" value="97877086"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #10</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877087"><label for="field_11-97877087"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877087" value="97877087"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #11</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="frm_catlevel_2">
        <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877090"><label for="field_11-97877090"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877090" value="97877090"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />PS #12</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877047"><label for="field_11-97877047"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877047" value="97877047"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Digital</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877048"><label for="field_11-97877048"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877048" value="97877048"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Inovasi</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="frm_catlevel_1">
    <div class="frm_checkbox" id="frm_checkbox_11-97877052"><label for="field_11-97877052"><input type="checkbox" name="item_meta[11][]" id="field_11-97877052" value="97877052"  data-frmlimit="1"  data-invmsg="Kategori is invalid"   />BI Religi</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

funny, you probably changed the page while i tested it , because i see you changed the checkboxes into selectbox... 
Anyway, By what i understand, you want that there will be only one checkbox checked
OR if its' sub-category, should be two - one sub category, and one the parent.

if so, this is the solution:

```
// remove your current listeners
$(':checkbox').off('click')
(function($)
{
    $(':checkbox').on('click', function()
    {
        // uncheck every checkbox
        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);

        // set initial variables
        var cekboks = $(this), hasParent;


        // tick the selected cekboks
        cekboks.prop('checked', true);
        console.log("cekboks", cekboks)

        // make sure has parents
        hasParent = cekboks.parents('.frm_catlevel_1')
        if(hasParent.length>0){
            // tick the parent category checkbox

            hasParent.find(":checkbox").first().prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: I am sorry to change the page while you tested it because I try to find the solution by using selectbox.

Comment: No problem. either way i finished testing :) you can use this code